# How to toggle outlet power to Eaton ePDU G3 from shell script

Tags: ssh, power-supply, shell-script, expect

I'm trying to programmatically toggle power to several outlets on a Eaton ePDU G3 using ssh via Jenkins CI shell script. This is to fire up lidars only during a Jenkins run.  It is not clear how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I figured out the syntax based on this document:
https://www.eaton.com/content/dam/eaton/products/backup-power-ups-surge-it-power-distribution/power-distribution-for-it-equipment/eaton-metered-outlet-rack-pdu/eaton-pdu-g3-instruction-set-objects-manual.pdf

To turn on outlet #1:

```
set PDU.OutletSystem.Outlet[1].DelayBeforeStartup 0
```

To turn off outlet #1:

```
set PDU.OutletSystem.Outlet[1].DelayBeforeShutdown 0
```

Now getting these commands scripted poses another problem since the login doesn't give you a bash shell but to a proprietary pdu interface.

So `sshpass` and `expect` to the rescue.

Here is an example of what worked within a Jenkinsfile:

```
post {
    always {
        sh """
            # turn off left lidar
            expect -c 'spawn sshpass -p${PDU_CREDS_PSW} ssh -v -oUserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -oHostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-dss  ${PDU_CREDS_USR}@${PDU_IP}; expect pdu#0; send -- "set PDU.OutletSystem.Outlet\\[1\\].DelayBeforeShutdown 0\\r"; expect pdu#0; send -- "quit\\r"; expect eof'
            # turn off right lidar
            expect -c 'spawn sshpass -p${PDU_CREDS_PSW} ssh -v -oUserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -oHostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-dss  ${PDU_CREDS_USR}@${PDU_IP}; expect pdu#0; send -- "set PDU.OutletSystem.Outlet\\[2\\].DelayBeforeShutdown 0\\r"; expect pdu#0; send -- "quit\\r"; expect eof'
        """
    }
}
```

Note that:

- `sshpass` is used to pass the password since a ssh private key is not an option
- `expect` is used to script the interactions https://linux.die.net/man/1/expect
- additional ssh flags like `HostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-dss` are required
- double backslashes `\\` are required to work properly within a Jenkinsfile